# force jquery function to work once

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

First, look at this : [ffisher](http://ghafaseh.ffisher.ir).
In this page i have somthing to happen after the mouse is over the box named "*جستجو*".
But the thing is if you move your mouse many times in and out, the animation will run for many times too.
i want this to be limited.
how can i use callbacks to reach this goal.

and another quetion is: i have used animating function to move the box down. the box is visible from begining. is this good or i should hide the box?

NEW : why blur doesn't work??? i want the blur to focus out from the input i have focused before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **stop** previous animation, use `.stop()` method before your `.animate()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-body").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#search-body").stop().animate({ top: '80px' });
        $("#search-text-box").focus();
    });

    $("#search-body").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#search-body").stop().animate({ top: '0px' });
        $("#search-text-box").blur();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your js file has syntax error, you missed `$` in your `mouseleave`, I've corrected here. `$("#search-text-box").blur();`.

Comment: wow... i think i am getting old! thanks. and what about the correctness of the work i am doing???